# PIL Get Image Palette

Tags: python, python-3.x

I opened an image and converted it to an image with a 16-color palette using this code:

```
im = Image.open("SomeImage.png")
im = im.convert("P")
im = im.convert("P", palette = Image.ADAPTIVE, colors = 16)
```

I can get the pixel data using:

```
im.getpixel((x,y))
```

Which returns an integer corresponding to the index of the color in the palette. How would I get the palette itself as a list of colors?

Comment: If you're looking for documentation for PIL, consider looking at the documentation of [pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/index.html) "the ‘friendly’ PIL fork", which contains details for [Image.getpalette](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.getpalette) and [Image.palette](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.palette)

Answer (score 4):

Your `im` has an `im.palette` attribute you could use -- but the recommended approach is instead to call `im.convert(mode)` (you can omit the `mode` argument to let PIL choose it optimally) to have PIL do the palette lookups internally on your behalf, much faster then you could.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to use `im.palette` to get the palette from a image, the image must have palette first.

I have faced the same confusion with you, so I write a `pip` module called `haishoku` to grab the palette color and dominant colors from any an image.

[Haishoku](https://github.com/LanceGin/haishoku)

Answer (score 2):

`im.getcolors()` worked for me when using the PIL module. It returns a list of the colors in the image in the following format: `[ ( count, rgbaColor ), ( count, rgbaColor ), ... ]`.

Comment: it just counts the colors. In the case of a paletted image, it returns (count,colorindex). Doesn't answer the question